# Not able to set compression mode to JPEG-LS in JAI

Tags: java, jpeg, jai

I am using JAI 1.1.3 for windows and configured Build path to include jai_codec , jai_core and jai_imageio jars.
When i try to write a image with JPEG-LS mode i get the error. Do i need to do any other configuration for JAI.

```
 import java.awt.image.renderable.ParameterBlock;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import javax.media.jai.JAI;
 import javax.media.jai.PlanarImage;

 public class JpegLs {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

   float x =0;
   float y =0;
   float width =100;
   float height =100;
   PlanarImage input = JAI.create("fileload", "bear.jpg");
    ParameterBlock pb = new ParameterBlock();
    pb.addSource(input);
    pb.add(x);
    pb.add(y);
    pb.add(width);
    pb.add(height);
    PlanarImage output = JAI.create("crop",pb,null);
    JAI.create("filestore",output,"abc.jpg","JPEG-LS"); 
   }
}
```

I am getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: FileStore The specified format has no associated registered ImageCodec.
at javax.media.jai.JAI.createNS(JAI.java:1087)
at javax.media.jai.JAI.create(JAI.java:973)
at javax.media.jai.JAI.create(JAI.java:1621)
at Sequence.Jai.main(Jai.java:25)
```

Comment: I am also searching for the similar solution, if u come to know, let me know please.